# How can I prevent this race condition from inserting duplicate records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-synapse

I have a simple stored procedure that can be called multiple times with the same `@param1` value in quick succession.

```
create proc Example(@param1 int, @param2 int, @param3 int)
as

if exists(select 1 from dbo.mytable where col1 = @param1)
begin
    update dbo.mytable
    set col2 = @param2, col3 = @param3
    where col1 = @param1
end

else
begin
    insert into dbo.mytable(col1, col2, col3) values(@param1, @param2, @param3)
end
```

We have seen duplicate records being inserted because of this. I know a primary key/unique constraint needs to be added to `col1`,  which will keep the data clean, but I still need to prevent an error from occurring.

How can I force the subsequent call to wait and update if an insert is already underway? Would wrapping this in a transaction help or do I need to add some kind of table or row lock?

**Update**
I can't use `MERGE` because it is not supported by our Data Warehouse. And, although it's in preview as pointed out in the comments, the link that wBob supplied shows that `MERGE` would have the same problem without changing the transaction isolation level. Unfortunately, the Data Warehouse does not support that isolation level or the table hint.

Comment: @MatBailie, this is a data warehouse. Unfortunately, `MERGE` is not supported.

Comment: put them in a [transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) inside your proc  maybe!? merge won't help,

Comment: https://michaeljswart.com/2017/07/sql-server-upsert-patterns-and-antipatterns/

Comment: Pretty sure MERGE is in preview:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/new-merge-command-for-azure-synapse-analytics/

Comment: @wBob, if I'm reading the link from MatBailie correctly, `MERGE` still wouldn't work correctly without using an isolation level that our Data Warehouse does not support :(

Comment: Yes interesting observation.  I would probably set up a trial to test it out, or "repro" as MS call it.  I think another answer is (and you probably won't like it) is not to use dedicated SQL pools like an OLTP database with fast running transactions that can potentially clash.  It's better as a batch system, big volumes of data.  As an alternative then, consider carving off your inserts into a separate table where duplicates would not matter and periodically inserting the distinct records into the main table, eg every hour.  Alternately, sit an Azure SQL DB in front.  Just a few ideas.